# Change CSS content attribute of a specific element

Tags: html, css

Given the style :

```
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
    content: "\039F";
    color: silver;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.6em;
}
```

and the objects :

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5">
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">One</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Two</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Three</li>
</ol>
```

How can I change the content property of the second object only , from

```
content: "\039F";
```

to

`content: "\2716";` ?

I tried :

```
<li class="progtrckr-todo" style="content: '\2716'">Two</li>
```

But it doesn't work .

Any idea how to make this work ?

Comment: `content` works only on pseudo elements (`:before`,  `:after`). You cannot overwrite it with an inline style since an inline style always applies to the element it's on.

Comment: You should pick the *best* answer, not the quickest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nth-child` to override the properties

```
ol.progtrckr :nth-child(2):before {
    content: "\2716";
}
```

Comment: The  `li.progtrckr-todo` part in your selector is misleading since neither element type nor class is taken into consideration by `:nth-child`.

Comment: @connexo Thank you for the info!

Comment: The only thing `:nth-child` does is ask ***one*** question: **Am I the nth child element of my parent?**

Answer (score 3):

`content` property is available only on pseudo elements (`:before`,  `:after`). You cannot overwrite it with an inline style since an inline style always applies to the element it's on, and pseudo elements are not part of the markup you can edit.

Use either [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) or [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo selector:

```
ol.progtrckr :nth-child(2):before {
    content: "\2716";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
ol.progtrckr :nth-child(2):before {
 content: "\2716";
}
```

you can refeer to this if its not exactly what you need

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: You miss a space between `ol.progtrckr` and `:nth-child(2):before`.

Answer (score 1):

The `content:''` property is a css property of the pseudo element `:before` and not the `li` element.

If you want to change the `content` programatically, you'd better just add some class to the `li` element, and override the `li.yourClass:before{content:'...'}` in your css.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that in you css styles it works with ":before". So you need to insert content before element.
You can use nth-child
[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Or just add specific class to sec element:

```
  secelementclass:before {
        content: "\2716";
    }

<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5">
<li class="progtrckr-todo">One</li>
<li class="progtrckr-todo secelementclass">Two</li>
<li class="progtrckr-todo">Three</li>
```